# TextField.text is assigned with a multi-line string, but they're not equal right after the assignment

Tags: string, actionscript-3, if-statement, textfield, multilinestring

I have an Array of strings:

```
private var phrase:Array = ["You will be given a series of questions like this:\n2 + 2 =\n(click or press ENTER to continue)","You can use the Keyboard or Mouse\nto deliver the answer\n\"ENTER\" locks it in.\n(click or press ENTER to continue)","\nClick Here\n to start."];
```

I have a conditional later in the script to see if the `phrase[0]` is equal to the `instructText.text`, so I put a "test" directly after the assignment as below:

```
instructText.text = phrase[0];
if (instructText.text == phrase[0]) {
    trace("phrase zero");
}
else {
    trace("nottttttttt");
}  

//OUTPUT: nottttttttt
```

I've tried various combinations of `phrase[0] as String` and `String(phrase[0])`, but haven't had any luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: Before the `if/else` statements why don't you just `trace("phrase 0 is : " + String(instructText.text) );` and what does it look like? Not equal / exact?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the `text` property of the `TextField` class converts the "Line Feed" characters (the `"\n"`, [ASCII code](http://ascii.cl/) of 10<sub>10</sub>=A<sub>16</sub>) to the character of "Carriage Return" (the ASCII code of 13<sub>10</sub>=D<sub>16</sub>).

So, you need a LF to CR conversion (or vise-versa) to make a homogeneous comparison of what is stored in the property against what you have in the array element:

```
function replaceLFwithCR(s:String):String {
    return s.replace(/\n/g, String.fromCharCode(13));
}
if (instructText.text == replaceCRwithLF(phrase[0])) {
    trace("They are equal :)");
}
else {
    trace("They are NOT equal :(");
}
// Output: They are equal :)
```

---

P.S. To get the code of a character, you may utilize the `charCodeAt()` method of the `String` class:

```
trace("\n".charCodeAt(0)); // 10
```